# Trouble using touchesEnded with a UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios, view, touch

I have been trying to play around with the touchedBegan, and touchedEnded. I basically am just trying to create an image in my view. Then be able to do something when the user touches the image. When I touch the image It does ever execute the code inside my if statement. Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

viewDidload:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage1.png"];
imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200);
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
imageViewsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:imageView, nil];
```

touchesEnded:

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    // do this on touch
    UIView *touchedView = [touch view];
    if ([imageViewsArray indexOfObject:touchedView] != NSNotFound) {
        // not not found means found!
        NSLog(@"Got Touch!");
    }
}
```

I also tried using this if statement:

```
if ([[touch view] isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        NSLog(@"Got Touch 2!");
}
```

Comment: check my post; i think ur problem is that u didn't set the property userInteractionEnabled of your UIImageView to YES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like DrummerB said i will recommend using the `UITapGestureRecognizer` instead. Have a look to the official doc [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH6-SW1) to get a good understanding of how it works but the main thing is to associate a gesture recognizer to the view that will handle the tap. In your case since you are dealing with a `UIImageView` make sure that you turn on the property `userInteractionEnabled` this is set to `NO` by default for the `UIImageView`: in another word the imageView are not picking up event by default.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks. If I wanted to take this one step further and create a UIScrollview, and a UIView and throw the UIImageView into that, then throw the UIView in too the UIScrollview. Would my code pick that up, or would I need to do some sub classing for that?

Comment: Found out my self, you do need to subclass. Because UIScrollView does not call the methods in my ViewController it overrides those methods. So I had to subclass UIScrollView and then overrides those methods. Thanks for your help!

Comment: just saw ur message - sorry i was out of SO!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be notified about a tap on your image view I recommend using a simpler approach using an [`UITapGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
// After initializing and adding your UIImageView:
UITapGestureRecognizer *gr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self       
                               action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:gr];
```

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gr {
    NSLog(@"Touched!");
}
```

If you want to stick with `touchesEnded`, try these steps:

- Check if your `imageViews` array is not `nil` in `touchesEnded`.
- Log `[touch view]` to see which view is receiving the touch.

Comment: Thanks! It looks as if my UIView is capturing the touch, but if I am touching the UIImageView and it is being added as subview of the UIView what would cause it to do that?

Comment: Is `touchesEnded` called at all? Is it called when you touch the image?